# jquery mobile back button

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a jquery mobile website that has a back button on every page except the first page. The back buttons should, as I understand them, take me back exactly one page ...to the page i was on before...HOWEVER, when I click the back button sometimes it will take me to the very first page (when i am three or four pages in) and other times it will take me back 2 pages.

```
<a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-icon-back ui-    btn-icon-notext ui-shadow ui-corner-all"  data-role="button" role="button">Back</a>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you actually transitioning between pages or just changing values on the current page? We need quite a bit more context here to understand what's happening.

Comment: Im transitioning between page 4 and page 3 but the back button takes me from page 4 to page 1

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For go to previous page use below code, You not assign id of back page.

```
<a href="#pagetwo">Go to Page Two</a>
```